# Magento2: Country Query is giving the duplicate of regions

Tags: magento2, graphql, country-regions

I am using the `country` query to retrieve information about a specific country. When I pass the country code as **AU**, in the available regions I am getting duplicate values as well as the code and name is showing as **"-"**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/directory-country.html#region

Below is the response I am getting:

```
{
    "data": {
        "country": {
            "id": "AU",
            "available_regions": [
                {
                    "id": 910,
                    "code": "AC",
                    "name": "Aust Capital Terr"
                },
                {
                    "id": 913,
                    "code": "NW",
                    "name": "New South Wales"
                },
                {
                    "id": 916,
                    "code": "QL",
                    "name": "Queensland"
                },
                {
                    "id": 919,
                    "code": "TA",
                    "name": "Tasmania"
                },
                {
                    "id": 922,
                    "code": "VC",
                    "name": "Victoria"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5127,
                    "code": "-",
                    "name": "-"
                },
                {
                    "id": 569,
                    "code": "ACT",
                    "name": "Australian Capital Territory"
                },
                {
                    "id": 570,
                    "code": "NSW",
                    "name": "New South Wales"
                },
                {
                    "id": 576,
                    "code": "NT",
                    "name": "Northern Territory"
                },
                {
                    "id": 572,
                    "code": "QLD",
                    "name": "Queensland"
                },
                {
                    "id": 573,
                    "code": "SA",
                    "name": "South Australia"
                },
                {
                    "id": 574,
                    "code": "TAS",
                    "name": "Tasmania"
                },
                {
                    "id": 571,
                    "code": "VIC",
                    "name": "Victoria"
                },
                {
                    "id": 575,
                    "code": "WA",
                    "name": "Western Australia"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I remove the duplicate regions as well as the "-".**
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to go phpmyadmin.
open table **`directory_country_region`**

search **`country_id = AU`**

OR

Run this below query :-

```
> SELECT * FROM `directory_country_region` WHERE `country_id` LIKE '%AU%'
```

After run query or search **`country_id`** by **`AU`** you shown this type.

[image]

Then, you get all the record related to country Austaliya ,delete the record that you want.

After you delete your duplicate regions, the output will show as per the same as below in the graphql query.

[image]

If any query let me know.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

=> Navigate to the admin panel.

=> From the main navigation menu, choose `Stores`.

=> Under `Region & City Manager`, select ***Manage Regions***.

You can then explore all regions in the grid and delete the one mentioned {id: 5127, name: "_"} by selecting it from the **Action** coloumn, as shown in the attached image.

Then you can check the respose data again, for this query:

```
query {
    country(id: "AU") {
        id
        two_letter_abbreviation
        three_letter_abbreviation
        full_name_locale
        full_name_english
        available_regions {
            id
            code
            name
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Double-check the base URL for the GraphQL instance you're working on.
- I am using Magento 2.4.6, so this answer is based on this version.

[image]

Comment: This does not look like a native Magento answer. I don't think such a menu exist. You might have some module installed on your Magento.